# Sorting and extracting of dirnames

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

There are a lot of directories named like

web001
web002
...
web123
...

I want to extract a max-number from this set...
Something like `num="´find -name /dirname sort ... | tail´"` with extracting. I have no ideas...

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just the number:

> find -type d -name web\* | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d'b' -f2

Comment: yeah, it does what I want, but with a little changes:
`find /path/to/find -type d -name "web*" | sort | tail -n 1 | cut -d'b' -f2`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `tr -dc [0-9]` to get rid of all non-numbers. Note that this also gets rid of the newline but if you extract just a single line with `tail`, that does not matter.

Answer (score 1):

```
ls | sort | tail -n 1
```

Will tell you what the last folder sorted alphabetically is

Comment: it becomes a wholename. I must extract a number yet. But thanks!